# Is there any FAA Regulation who may wash a private aircraft such as Cessna Skyhawk or Citation?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance, private-jets, cleaning

Should it be mandatory to hire a mechanic? or someone else with any kind of FAA license? or could anyone wash one?

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26169/62)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any yahoo can wash a plane...even a pilot.

The only regulation of which I am aware concerning washes involves maintenance.  A maintainer must clean the aircraft in order to determine servicability of a component.  The regulation does not specify who must do the cleaning, however.  I doubt a FSDO (in the US) would read that as "A&P must clean it."

Comment: Any yahoo *can* wash it, but not any yahoo [*should wash it*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroper%C3%BA_Flight_603).

Comment: @RonBeyer, [XL Airways Germany flight 888T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XL_Airways_Germany_Flight_888T) is even better example as that accident was contributed by the washing technique itself rather than just failure to remove covers installed for it.

Comment: @JanHudec Another very good example, yes. At least in the 888T case they couldn't know during preflight, the 603 crew should have caught that in the walk around.

Comment: All good points but those are both airliners, not "private planes."  Common damage typically involves broken or bent antennas, use of windex on windows, and use of corrosive chemicals (like regular Sumple Green) to clean oil and grease.

Comment: I agree with Ron.  As far as regulations are concerned the onus falls on the maintenance personnel and pilots to ensure that a plane is still airworthy after being washed.

Comment: What about the cleaning required at annual, which shall be done by the IA?

Comment: That reg does not specify the extent to which the airplane must be cleaned, only that the plane must be clean enough for the IA to assess airworthiness.  My IA indicated that he may clear a small area of grease to assess the condition of a questionable grease fitting, for example, but is not going to clean the whole plane.

Answer (score 7):

There is no regulation on who can wash a plane. You'll probably find that quite a few planes (at least of those used for instruction) are in fact washed by student pilots.